# How to remove duplicate rows from a CSV file?

Tags: php, csv

Is there a simple way to find and remove duplicate rows from a CSV file?

Sample test.csv file:

```
row1 test tyy......
row2 tesg ghh
row2 tesg ghh
row2 tesg ghh
....
row3 tesg ghh
row3 tesg ghh
...
row4 tesg ghh
```

Expected results:

```
row1 test tyy......
row2 tesg ghh
....
row3 tesg ghh
...
row4 tesg ghh
```

Where can I start to accomplish this with PHP?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Is it true that all duplicate lines really do appear consecutively?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A straight-to-the point method would be to read the file in line-by-line and keep track of each row you've previously seen. If the current row has already been seen, skip it.

Something like the following (untested) code may work:

```
<?php
// array to hold all "seen" lines
$lines = array();

// open the csv file
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== false) {
    // read each line into an array
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 8192, ",")) !== false) {
        // build a "line" from the parsed data
        $line = join(",", $data);

        // if the line has been seen, skip it
        if (isset($lines[$line])) continue;

        // save the line
        $lines[$line] = true;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

// build the new content-data
$contents = '';
foreach ($lines as $line => $bool) $contents .= $line . "\r\n";

// save it to a new file
file_put_contents("test_unique.csv", $contents);
?>
```

This code uses [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and uses a <s>space</s> comma as your column-delimiter (based on the sample-data in your <s>question</s> comment).

Storing every line that has been seen, as above, will assure to remove all duplicate lines in the file regardless of whether-or-not they're directly following one another or not. If they're always going to be back-to-back, a more simple method (and more memory conscious) would be to store only the last-seen line and then compare against the current one.

**UPDATE** (duplicate lines via the SKU-column, not full-line)
Based on sample data provided in a comment, the "duplicate lines" aren't actually equal (though they are similar, they differ by a good number of columns). The similarity between them can be linked to a single column, the `sku`.

The following is an expanded version of the above code. This block will parse the first line (column-list) of the CSV file to determine which column contains the `sku` code. From there, it will keep a unique list of SKU codes seen and if the current line has a "new" code, it will write that line to the new "unique" file using [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/fputcsv):

```
<?php
// array to hold all unique lines
$lines = array();

// array to hold all unique SKU codes
$skus = array();

// index of the `sku` column
$skuIndex = -1;

// open the "save-file"
if (($saveHandle = fopen("test_unique.csv", "w")) !== false) {
    // open the csv file
    if (($readHandle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== false) {
        // read each line into an array
        while (($data = fgetcsv($readHandle, 8192, ",")) !== false) {
            if ($skuIndex == -1) {
                // we need to determine what column the "sku" is; this will identify
                // the "unique" rows
                foreach ($data as $index => $column) {
                    if ($column == 'sku') {
                        $skuIndex = $index;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if ($skuIndex == -1) {
                    echo "Couldn't determine the SKU-column.";
                    die();
                }
                // write this line to the file
                fputcsv($saveHandle, $data);
            }

            // if the sku has been seen, skip it
            if (isset($skus[$data[$skuIndex]])) continue;
            $skus[$data[$skuIndex]] = true;

            // write this line to the file
            fputcsv($saveHandle, $data);
        }
        fclose($readHandle);
    }
    fclose($saveHandle);
}
?>
```

Overall, this method is far-more memory friendly as it doesn't need to save a copy of every line in memory (only the SKU codes).

Comment: Duplicates should only be removed if the row is repeated. If the same row comes back later in the CSV it should be included.

Comment: @ArnoldDaniels I see no such statement in the post regarding that. Please let me know where you received that information from and I can update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Take a look at the 'Expected results'. You can see the non-unique rows.

Comment: i am sorry, after run the code, when open the test_unique.csv. the data are mixed and disorderly

Comment: @user1932607 Unordered? It will put the contents back into the file in the same order it read it in. Is the answer supposed to, in addition to removing duplicates, order the data as well?

Comment: The code does not result in the requested 'Expected results'. If the user does want a unique list it should use @lng's code which is much simpler.

Comment: @ArnoldDaniels Actually, it *does* follow the 'Expected results', to the letter. @Ing's code is the same as mine except he uses `in_array()` instead of `isset()` (I use `isset()` because `in_array()` will be slow down as the #-of-lines increases). The other difference is he reads the full file in all-at-once, I parse it line-by-line using a function made for CSV files (again, I read line-by-line because a large file will be painful to read in all-at-once).

Comment: i cut some part of my csv file. could you do a test to my csv file.http://down123.xxmn.com/a.csv thank you.

Comment: @user1932607 There are no duplicate rows in the file you linked to. However, the columns in your file are comma-separated, but in your question are space-separated. I'll update my answer to reflect that change. I tested my code against your provided .csv file and it worked fine; I manually duplicated lines in it and it also worked fine. Is there some special method you need/use to detect duplicate lines or is "this full line is the same as this full line" enough?

Comment: the AS087  have two lines .if you search it ,you will find

Comment: @user1932607 We must be looking at different sets of data because those two lines are **not** the same. Even Ing stated they're not the same. Regardless, I've updated my answer to show how you can also perform sku-code duplicate stripping in the event that the actual lines themselves are different. Hopefully this is something you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One line solution:

```
file_put_contents('newdata.csv', array_unique(file('data.csv')));
```

Comment: Did you test this ?