# How to remove duplicate emails in csv file

Tags: php, email, csv

How to remove duplicate email address in different csv file

example: 
I have 10.000 emails address (all_members.csv) after sent out > Then I received 2550 invalid email (invalid.csv)

I want to remove that "invalid email"

My Code "

```
    <?php
$all = file('all_email.csv'); // all_members.csv
$invalid = file('invalid.csv'); // invalid_email.csv
$correctEmails=array_diff($all, $invalid); 

foreach ($correctEmails as $email) { echo $email."<br>"; }
$result = array_intersect($all,$invalid);
?>
```

[for remove email only > this php code is work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3te9l.gif)

[the problem is if I want to remove emails under "Multiple columns"  is Not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6AkZ.gif)
anyone can help

I would greatly appreciate if you able to help me, thanks

Comment: loop,compare,write new

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate rows from a CSV file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071791/how-to-remove-duplicate-rows-from-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend encapsulating this in a function that streams each line, builds an array of field -> values then checks to see if the value is in the data you want to remove, if it's not, write the line to an out file.

Something like...

```php
<?php 
/**
 * Given a CSV file to read, the delimiter, and what to remove, return the filtered CSV data
 * @param $filename     string  The /path/to/file.csv
 * @param $outputFile   string  Where to write the output CSV data to
 * @param $delimiter    string  How the fields are delimited in the CSV 
 * @param $removeHeader string  The header to remove data from 
 * @param $removeData   array   The data to omit from the output 
 * 
 * @return boolean
 **/
function remove_duplicates($filename, $outputFile, $delimiter=',', $removeHeader, $removeData)
{
    // If the file doesn't exist or isn't readable - return false
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename)) { 
        return false;
    }
    $header = null;
    $validData = []; 
    $writeHandle = fopen($outputFile, 'w');
    if (false !== ($readHandle = fopen($filename, 'r'))) {
        //While there are rows in the CSV, get this as an array of values
        while (false !== ($row = fgetcsv($readHandle, 1000, $delimiter))) {
            //On the first iteration, get the headers from the CSV
            if (!$header) {
                $header = $row;
                fputcsv($writeHandle, $header);
            } else {
                // Combine the headers with the row to create an associative array representing a line
                $line = array_combine($header, $row);
                // Looking at the removeHeader field in this line, check to see if the value is in removeData
                if (!in_array($line[$removeHeader], $removeData) {
                    // If it's not, then it's a valid line
                    fputcsv($writeHandle, $line);  
                }
            }
        }
        fclose($readHandle);
        fclose($writeHandle);
    }
    // Return 
    return true;
}
```